# How to get a spark job's metrics?

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-spark, ganglia

we have a cluster which has about 20 nodes. This cluster is shared among many users and jobs. Therefore, it is very difficult for me to observe my job so that I can get some metrics such as CPU usage, I/O, Network, Memory etc...

How can I get a metrics on job level.

PS: The cluster already have Ganglia installed but not sure how I could get it to work on the job level. What I would like to do is monitor the resource used by the cluster to execute my job only.

Comment: Not sure if understand you correctly. You want to get different cluster metrics right from your job? Or you want to know how much resources your job uses?

Comment: @maxteneff, sorry if I was not clear on my post. I want to know how much resources my job used.

Comment: I'm curious what you ended up doing to retrieve your metrics?

Comment: Can you also answer the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327187/how-to-evaluate-e2e-performance-of-spark-streaming-job-in-particular-the-durat

Answer (score 3):

You can get the spark job metrics from Spark History Server, which displays information about:
 *- A list of scheduler stages and tasks

 - A summary of RDD sizes and memory usage

 - A Environmental information

 - A Information about the running executors*

1, Set **spark.eventLog.enabled** to true before starting the spark application. This configures Spark to log Spark events to persisted storage.
2, Set **spark.history.fs.logDirectory**, this is the directory that contains application event logs to be loaded by the history server;
3, Start the history server by executing: **./sbin/start-history-server.sh**

please refer to below link for more information:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html